# gradient descent algorithm dealing with a cost function not known at start time?

Tags: algorithm, optimization, gradient-descent, robotics

I am working on a homework in which I have to simulate a robot which moves in a 2-dimensional space and must maximize an objective function (signal quality).

This robot can read the value of the function in a specific position only when it reaches this position ( the function is not known when the algorithm starts, but the robot discovers a value in each position it visits).

Moreover, this optimization function changes overtime, so the goal of this project is to configure a robot who keeps moving in order to ptimize the position.

Can you have some idea about gradient descent  with optimization function not known at starting time and which changes during the execution of the algorithm? If you suggest me papers, books, codes or whatever I would really appreciate that.

Thank you

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stochastic_gradient_descent?

Comment: I'm not sure if gradient descent is a good idea since a robot that moves continuously along a path can hardly evaluate a 2d gradient without moving in weird patterns. A simple line search (go in a given direction until the function value decreases) might be more appropriate. Once you are at a local maximum, you can go in a circle to find a new direction.